# How to do arithmetic operation in TDE

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I have requirement to get previous date of one of the date field, for that I am doing below operation in TDE. But I am getting error on this operation. How can I achieve this

```
<tde:column>
<tde:name>PreStartDate</tde:name>
<tde:scalar-type>date</tde:scalar-type>
<tde:val>(hdm:StartDate - xs:dayTimeDuration("P1D"))</tde:val>
<tde:nullable>true</tde:nullable>
</tde:column>
```

Comment: What error is shown? Have you tried testing your TDE from QConsole against a sample document? You may need to cast the value of your StartDate element to xs:date or xs:dateTime if you don't have an XML Schema loaded into MarkLogic that specifies its type.

Comment: hdm:StartDate  is already in Date format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your comment stating that `hdm:StartDate` is already in Date format. As written, however, what you have is a string that looks like a Date (well, more precisely an `untypedAtomic`). It needs to be converted to an actual date type before you can subtract a `dayTimeDuration` from it.

```
<tde:column>
  <tde:name>PreStartDate</tde:name>
  <tde:scalar-type>date</tde:scalar-type>
  <tde:val>(xs:date(hdm:StartDate) - xs:dayTimeDuration("P1D"))</tde:val>
  <tde:nullable>true</tde:nullable>
</tde:column>
```